# Calling SignalR from API at another project - No error nor notification

Tags: c#, api, signalr

I have a WebSite integrated with SignalR. It functions well, and it has a button which sends popup notification to all clients who are online. It works well when I click on the button.

My API is in another project but in the same Solution. I want to send the above notification by calling from the API side. Basically, a mobile app will send a request to API and then API will send a notification to all online web clients.

Below code runs and not gives the notification nor any error.

Is this fundamentally correct? Appreciate your help

**API code (at WebAPI project)**

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<string> WatchMe(int record_id)
{
    GMapChatHub sendmsg = new GMapChatHub();
    sendmsg.sendHelpMessage(record_id.ToString());

    return "Done";
}
```

**C# code (at Web project)**

```
namespace GMapChat
{
    public class GMapChatHub : Hub
    {
        public void sendHelpMessage(string token)
        {
             var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<GMapChatHub>();
             context.Clients.All.helpMessageReceived(token, "Test help message");
        }
    }
}
```

**Home.aspx file (at Web project)**

```
var chat = $.connection.gMapChatHub;

        $(document).ready(function () {
            chat.client.helpMessageReceived = function (token,msg) {
                console.log("helpMessageReceived: " + msg);

                $('#helpMessageBody').html(msg)
                $('#helpModal').modal('toggle');
            };
          }
```

Comment: Can you attach to and breakpoint on the sendHelpMessage and invoke the api call?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment Ross. Yes I call comes through the sendHelpMessage method when I call the API. But it just goes over it only. No exception or errors. Just passing through.

Comment: The you should be able to trace a hop if you have a client open, do you see anything over the wire? You might have to fire up two instances of your debugger.

Comment: @RossBush Yes, I run two instances which open in two browsers in localhost (with different ports). Still it doesn't show anything in console :( It doesn't even work in the server where it hosted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not call that hub directly. Firs you need to install the .net client for SignalR from [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client). Then you need to initialize it  like this :

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<string> WatchMe(int record_id)
{   
   using (var hubConnection = new HubConnection("your local host address")) 
   {
    IHubProxy proxy= hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("GMapChatHub");
     await hubConnection.Start();
    proxy.Invoke("sendHelpMessage",record_id.ToString());     // invoke server method
  } 
// return sth. IEnumerable<string>
}
```

And opening a new connection per request may not be good idea you may make it per session (if you use) or static or time fashioned.

Comment: Thank you ! I tried this, but it doesn't reach to my "sendHelpMessage" class which is in another project.

Comment: @Smug you don't have to reach that class. You need to connect that hub and it should be running while you trying to connect from your other project.

Comment: Understand. It still passes through. No error or no reaction in server-side. It doesn't give the popup or no any logs in browser debug.

Comment: Thank you ! Your answer is correct. I had a second parameter which had a default value assigned. Still, I have to pass a value for that. I was struggling there. You above code work perfectly. Thank you!